# Configuring Google Cloud Load Balancer path rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to configure the Google Cloud loadbalancer to do the following:

- I have a website running on a Wordpress machine in a VM instance which I want users to access when they enter `outairnet.com`.
- And I have a separate html file that I want users to access when they access `outairnet.com/map`.
- WP is running on a compute engine VM, connected to a VM instance and to a backend service. The seperate html file is on a service bucket, connected to a backend bucket.

I've triedd to configure a very simple path forwarding rule, which made sense to me. But it just adds up to anyone trying to access `outairnet.com/*` gets to the WP (which is fine)
but accessing `outairnet.com/map` doesn't point to the storage bucket with the html file, however accessing `outairnet.com/index.html` does point to the separate html file.

My LB config [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQX6z.png).

---

I think I'm on to the problem but still can't solve it.

it looks like google console adds a /* rule even when I try to delete it.

so its a /* path rule that catches everything despite having a more specific rule like /mypath/* in addition.

but after removing it is just readded automatically for some reason. why?

Comment: try path as `/map/*` and visit `outairnet.com/map/whatever.html`

Comment: In addition of @Asdfg solution, can  you put your file in the path `/map/` in the bucket?

Comment: tried doing both things.

now outairnet.com takes the user to the WP on the VM which is good.
but anything else outairnet.com/whatever - gives a 404 not found

Comment: I just added another path rule with just "/" directing to the VM and it seemed to do it, but now the only glitch is www.outairnet.com/map is fine but outairnet.com/map without www directs to the vm and not the bucket

Answer (score 2):

It's possible - there are a few steps involved such as creating a bucket with your static page, adding it as a backend service in your load balancer and creating a new path-rule in it to redirect the requests.

**And now the details:**

1. **[Create a new bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#create-bucket)** - pick the name you like (outairnet-static or something that will be meaningful to you so you don't delete by accident). You can ignore all the tutorials telling that it has to have the exact name of your domain - since it will only be hosting a file accessible under `outairnet.com/mylink/` it will work regardless of the name used. I tested it.
2. **Create a directory in your bucket** named exactly ax the path under which you want it to be. If you want `outairnet.com/mylink/` then directory's name has to be `mylink`. [Upload your files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading) into that directory. Name your main index file `index.html` unless you want to provide full file path.
3. **[Make the bucket avaialble to everyone](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#sharing)**.
4. **Go to your LB configuration and edit backend services**; [add a new backend bucket](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets#creating_the_http_load_balancer_with_backend_buckets).

[image]

5. **Go to your Host and Path Rules and configure a new path**; Enter the name of your site and the path (**Remember that the path value must be `/mylink/*`.**) and select the bucket you've just created from the dropdown list.

[image]

**No changes necessary for the frontend. Save the changes and in a few moments it should be working.**

Comment: i've tried all of the above but still get page not found when accessing outairnet.com/map or outairnet.com/whatever.

Comment: I just added another path rule with just "/" directing to the VM and it seemed to do it, but now the only glitch is www.outairnet.com/map is fine but outairnet.com/map without www directs to the vm and not the bucket

Answer (score 0):

I just added another path rule with just "/" directing to the VM and it seemed to do it, but now the only glitch is [www.outairnet.com/map](http://www.outairnet.com/map) is fine but outairnet.com/map without www directs to the vm and not the bucket