# How to fetch newly added images from VM in google cloud platform?

Tags: image, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I add images it is stored inside google cloud platform VM correctly.
But I am not able to fetch newly added images in my website.
If I redeploy project with newly added images in assets folder it is showing correctly.
I have verified there is no mistake on frontend or backend side.

Is it not possible to get live image update with VM?

**Edit:**

I have used Vue.js.

I am storing images inside `src/assets` folder.
When I save images in my website it is saved at `src/assets` folder.

I think it can only access things in dist folder after build.
Can you suggest where should I save my file?

Comment: Do you have local cache in your VM? How do you fetch and serve this image?

Comment: Please update quor question with more details about your setup, os & software etc. For the moment there isn't enough information to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an educateg guess it's some cache issue.

Instead of putting your image files inside the VM you can try storing them in a [bucket that's accessible to public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). The downside is that it can serve only static files (no PHP or anything).

You have to configure your load balancer to forward all `your.domain.com/images/` requests to the bucket but that's actually quite easy. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435034/12257250) asking for such configuration.